# Perl regexp matching

Tags: regex, perl

EDIT : I have some difficult to express myself. Let me start again.
I have a loop that read string from a file :

```
GigabitEthernet0/0
GigabitEthernet0/1
GigabitEthernet0/2
Serial0/0/0:0
Serial0/0/0:0.100
```

And i'm trying some regexp to get the interface **Serial0/0/0:0**

```
if ($lineSplitter[2] =~ /Serial0(.*):0[^(.\d)](.*)/ && $interfacebool eq "false"){
    $interfaceNeeded = $lineSplitter[2] ;
}
```

But it is not working.
I tried several things on an online REGEXP simulator but still.. Without result...
All i want is to get the **main interface** (Serial0/0/0:0), **not the sub-interface** (Serial0/0/0:0.100)

EXPECTED VARIABLE:

```
Serial0/0/0:0
```

I don't want to replace, or get a part of the sub-interface. I want the regexp to match the main interface without matching the sub-one

Sorry for this misunderstanding.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Are we supposed to understand what "interface" and "sub-interface" refers to?

Comment: Sorry, i edited to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict your match, use anchors, `^` to match beginning of string, and `$` to match end of string:

```
/^Serial0(.*):0$/
```

This will only match your `Serial` strings that end with `:0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece:

```
perl -ne 'print if $_ =~ /Serial0\/\d\/\d:\d$/' data.txt
```

will match `Serial0/x/x:x` (e.g. not `Serial0/0/0:0.100`)

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful?

```
m/^Serial[^\.]*[\s\n\r]/g
```